# Есть ли производные от слова?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли слово **понуждать** и его производные — **понуждаемый, понуждаемых**?

Answer (score 2):

Сошлюсь на словари.

Значение слова Понуждать по Ефремовой:

> Понуждать - 1. Заставлять, принуждать что-л. делать; побуждать к чему-л. 
>   2. Погонять, понукать лошадей.

Значение слова Понуждать по словарю Ушакова:

> ПОНУЖДАТЬ 
>   понуждаю, понуждаешь (книжн.). Несов. к понудить.

Значение слова Понуждать по словарю Даля:

> Понуждать 
>   понужать; понудить кого к чему, побуждать, заставлять, принуждать, нудить, неволить, силить; поощрять, подстрекать. Крайность понуждает к просьбам. Понудь-ка лошаденку, подгони.

Соответственно, существуют и производные от этого глагола.